# NodeJS request to Rails app on localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, http, request

I have this in my NodeJS server (node 9.3.0) and I'm getting a `ECONNREFUSED`.

```
request({ 
  method: 'POST', 
  url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3050/v1/clinician' 
}, (err, httpResponse, body) => { 
  console.log('CONNECT ERROR', err) 
})
```

On the rails side I'm running the app with `rails s -p 3050`.

If I run the same exact command from the `node` CLI then I get a response. I also get a response with this sample CURL

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:3050/v1/clinician \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d '{"clinician": { "access_token": "test"} }'
```

I also tried with the npm `http` library like so and get the same error.

```
const httpRequest = http.request({
  hostname: '127.0.0.1', // or localhost
  port: 3050,
  path: '/v1/clinician',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}, (response) => {
  console.log(`STATUS: ${response.statusCode}`)
}).on('error', (e) => {
  console.log(`problem with request: ${e.message}`)
})
```

Given that it works in the CLI and cURL, I'm assuming it has to do with the NodeJS app itself being the source of the request.

Comment: What are the logs in the Rails server when doing the request?

Comment: When I hit it via cURL, I get a response and I can deal with that but when I hit it via the node app there is not log change

Comment: Not sure, that's why I ask, is by default the request made, a JSON format request?, you're passing a token in the CURL example, but not with request, have you checked that difference?

Comment: The `http` library example is using port 4000, while the rails app is running on port 3050

Comment: @SebastianPalma yes it's a json request and it can be empty. If the rails server were responding then it would throw an error but I can deal with that. Just need to get a response.

Comment: @shaochuancs I was playing around with the port to see if that was the issue but it wasn't. I tried on a few different ones while spinning up the rails app on those and no difference

Comment: I thought it may have to do with the fact that the Node app is running in docker and the rails one isn't so localhost would refer to docker's localhost and not my machine's localhost. I've since added the rails app to the docker config and no luck

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I needed to first dockerize my rails app so it was on the same host (in the docker VM) as the node app. I then needed to make the request with `http://<container_name>:3050` rather than `http://localhost:3050`.